# Javafx custom cursor reverts to system when hovering over background

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have added a default cursor:

```
someScene.setCursor(getSomeCursor());
```

This is working. I have this cursor-code working everywhere in my application, and it looks fine. But whenever I hover over a background GUI component, even if that background component, (be that a VBox, a Canvas or whatever), uses the correct cursor itself, the cursor reverts to the system cursor, instead of my custom cursor.

Any help appreciated.

Here is a complete worked example, which exactly produces the problem: the http link to that "blue cursor" was live at the time of posting. But please check if you get a problem reproducing.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.ImageCursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class CursorTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        SomeDialog someDialog = new SomeDialog(stage);
        GridPane root = new GridPane();

        HBox buttonHolder= new HBox();
        buttonHolder.setPrefSize(300,300);

        Scene theScene = new Scene(root);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setWidth(300);
        canvas.setHeight(300);
        canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.RED);
        canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRoundRect(100, 100, 100, 100, 10, 10);

        Image cursorImg = new Image("http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Cursor-Arrow-PNG-Transparent-Image.png");
        ImageCursor imageCursor = new ImageCursor(cursorImg);
        theScene.setCursor(imageCursor);
        stage.setTitle("Ribbon dialog");
        stage.setScene(theScene);
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().add(canvas);
        vBox.setSpacing(50);

        Button button = new Button("Show modal");
        button.setPadding(new Insets(30,30,30,30));
        button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            someDialog.showMeAndWait();
        });
        buttonHolder.getChildren().add(button);

        root.getChildren().addAll(vBox, buttonHolder);
        stage.show();
    }

    class SomeDialog {

        Stage newStage;

        public SomeDialog(Stage primaryStage) {
            newStage = new Stage();
            GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
            Scene theScene = new Scene(gridPane);

            Image cursorImg = new Image("http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Cursor-Arrow-PNG-Transparent-Image.png");
            ImageCursor imageCursor2 = new ImageCursor(cursorImg);
            theScene.setCursor(imageCursor2);
            theScene.setCursor(imageCursor2);
            theScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            newStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            newStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            newStage.setTitle("Player inventory");
            newStage.setScene(theScene);
            newStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

            VBox vBox = new VBox();
            Button someBtn = new Button("Close");
            someBtn.setPadding(new Insets(100,100,100,100));
            someBtn.setOnMouseClicked(event -> newStage.close());
            vBox.getChildren().add(someBtn);
            gridPane.getChildren().add(vBox);
        }

        public void showMeAndWait() {
            newStage.showAndWait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help here so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Possibly related to this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091628

Comment: Update: I've logged this as a bug with Oracle: internal ID = 9051152

Comment: If anyone has a workaround, I'd really appreciate it.